# how to encrypt the data using node and decrypt data using only webcrypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, webcrypto-api

How to encrypted server data from node js stored in indexeddb and decrypted data from indexeddb using webcrypto technology

And it works on offline mode also...And then if using rsa encryption how to use that same key values which can be used in webcrypto ..

Comment: In your opinion, have you provided enough information for anyone to be able to answer this question?

Comment: you can use crypto core module of node js for encryption and decryption

Comment: my requirement is decryption must done on webcrypto..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site for examples of using webcrypto: https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples

For how to store a key in indexdb see:
https://gist.github.com/saulshanabrook/b74984677bccd08b028b30d9968623f5

On node you will need:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webcrypto-ossl

Comment: while i m storing and retrieve the object from pouch db  i am facing this issues "Failed to execute 'decrypt' on 'SubtleCrypto': parameter 2 is not of type 'CryptoKey'".